# Jmeter cannot substitute regular expression reference in Body Data of HTTP Request

Tags: regex, json, jmeter, blazemeter

I would like to extract value of `ProductIdentifier` in json response as below:

```
Reference Name: ProductToken
Regular Expression: "ProductIdentifier":" (.+?)"
Template $1$
Match No. 1
```

Then `ProductToken` reference will be used in payload of requests (json) for validation.

There are tutorials and videos to describe how to substitute the reference name as example below:
[jmeter-video-tutorial-error-checking-and-dynamic](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/207652-jmeter-video-tutorial-error-checking-and-dynamic)

Currently the reference name `${ProductToken}` is not replaced with its value (taken from previous response) in request, it is recognized as plain text of reference name.

```
{"order":{"Token":null,"ProductIdentifier":"${ProductToken}","OrderToken":null,"Products": ...
```

There are more than 30 variables in request, It is waste of time to write them as parameter instead of substitution in Body Data directly each time for substitution.

I could not find anyway to use this reference name in Body Data of HTTP Request. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try dropping the quotes around `"${ProductToken}"`

Comment: Both the regular expression extractor & the sampler - are they in the same thread group?  As you get response in the JSON format - can you json post processor to extract the value- that is easier than regular expression extractor?

Comment: It does not work without double quotes neither. I am using blazemeter with jmx file. I am not sure whether blazemeter supports json post processor  api. Anyway, I am able to extract the value but the problem is about putting the value from former response to next request. What expected is passing string value (ex. c1e8e382-771e-4fee-b7c2-0a24afe798df) in Body Data instead of something like this : 
{"order":{"Token":null,"ProductIdentifier":"${ProductToken}",

Comment: When I need to build massive Bodies, I tend to add a BeanShell PreProcessor to the call, build a string there, save it, and then just add that one string to your body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment the most comfortable way to process JSON responses seems to be custom [JSON utils](https://github.com/ATLANTBH/jmeter-components/) for jmeter (JSON Path Assertion, JSON Path Extractor, JSON Formatter) which are also part of [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ExtrasWithLibsSet/) and should work fine along with Blazemeter.

Using JSON Path instead of Regular Expression Extractor may help you to avoid processing errors caused by json formatting issues.

If `ProductIdentifier` appearance is unique in response the following one should work fine in this particular case:

`{
   "order":{
      "Token":null,
      "ProductIdentifier":"c1e8e382-771e-4fee-b7c2-0a24afe798df",
      "OrderToken":null,
      "Products":[
         "one",
         "two",
         "three"
      ]
   }
}`

```
. . .
HTTP Request
    jp@gc - JSON Path Extractor
    Name: productToken
    JSON path: $.order.ProductIdentifier
HTTP Request
Body Data:
    {
       "order":{
          "Token":null,
          "ProductIdentifier":"${productToken}",
          "OrderToken":null,
          "Products":[
             "one",
             "two",
             "three"
          ]
       }
    }
. . .
```

Comment: Thanks @aliaksandr-belik I will check the performance impact of json path extractor's processing overhead ;)